# Draw rectangle in each highchart scatter portion

Tags: highcharts

[hey this is me Ahmed wanted to draw a rectangle in each section of scattering which I created already I have to draw a rectangle inside in each partition the js fiddle example also helps you to figure out my problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5UU8.png)

this is the example js fiddle link

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      events: {
        load: function() {
          var chart = this,
            r = chart.renderer,
            each = Highcharts.each,
            left = chart.plotLeft,
            top = chart.plotTop,
            h = chart.plotHeight,
            w = chart.plotWidth,
            xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
            yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
            labels = ['top-left', 'top-right', 'bottom-left', 'bottom-right'],
            labelStyles = {
              'font-size': '12px',
              'color': 'red'
            },
            attr = {
              zIndex: 10
            },
            xPlotLine, yPlotLine,bbox, x, y;

          chart.label = [];
                    
          xPlotLine = xAxis.toPixels(xAxis.plotLinesAndBands[0].options.value);
          yPlotLine = yAxis.toPixels(yAxis.plotLinesAndBands[0].options.value);

                    
          //render
          each(labels, function(label, i) {
          
            chart.label[i] = r.text(label, 0, 0)
              .attr(attr)
              .css(labelStyles)
              .add();
              
            bbox = chart.label[i].getBBox();
              console.log(w);
            switch(i) {
                case 0:
                x = ((xPlotLine + left) / 2) - (bbox.width / 2);
                y = ((yPlotLine + top) / 2) - (bbox.height / 2);
                break;
              case 1:
                x = left + xPlotLine + ((w - xPlotLine)/2) - (bbox.width / 2);
                y = ((yPlotLine + top) / 2) - (bbox.height / 2);
                break;
              case 2:
                x = ((xPlotLine + left) / 2) - (bbox.width / 2);
                y = top + yPlotLine + ((h - yPlotLine) / 2) - (bbox.height / 2);
                break;
              case 3:
                x = left + xPlotLine + ((w - xPlotLine)/2) - (bbox.width / 2);
                y = top + yPlotLine + ((h - yPlotLine) / 2) - (bbox.height / 2);
                break;
            }
            
            chart.label[i].attr({
                x: x,
              y: y
            });
          });

        }
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      plotLines: [{
        id: 'ver',
        color: '#FF0000',
        width: 2,
        value: 2
      }]
    },
    yAxis: {
      plotLines: [{
        id: 'hor',
        color: '#FF0000',
        width: 2,
        value: 100
      }]
    },

    series: [{
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
  });
});


http://jsfiddle.net/x1zna57a/
```

i want to draw a rectangle in each partition please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Consider posting this on the puzzle stack exchange if you want people to "figure out your problem" for themselves. Here most people are willing to answer concrete questions. Stating your problem in a clear question is perceived to be your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use the `polygon` series to draw those rectangles. The advantage of this solution is that this will keep your chart and those rectangles responsive.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hL6kf28z/

```
series: [{
  type: 'polygon',
  data: [
    [0, 0],
    [2, 0],
    [2, 100],
    [0, 100]
  ],
  enableMouseTracking: false,
  color: 'gray'
}, {
  type: 'polygon',
  data: [
    [0, 100],
    [2, 100],
    [2, 250],
    [0, 250]
  ],
  enableMouseTracking: false,
  color: 'gray'
}, {
  type: 'polygon',
  data: [
    [2, 0],
    [11, 0],
    [11, 100],
    [2, 100]
  ],
  enableMouseTracking: false,
  color: 'gray'

}, {
  type: 'polygon',
  data: [
    [2, 100],
    [11, 100],
    [11, 250],
    [2, 250]
  ],
  enableMouseTracking: false,
  color: 'gray'

}, {
  data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}]
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.polygon